# Snowflake warehouse: get all roles (including inherited ones) assigned to a user

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get all the roles a user is part of. In my case, the user is part of an admin role which inherits another role ingestor, this inherits another role analyst. If I query from snowflake like as follows:

```
show grants to user <userid>
```

This lists only the admin role but not other two roles (ingestor, analyst). If the same user logs into snowflake, he could see all three roles available for him in the role dropdown.

Need help to get all explicit roles irrespective of role inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

As a start, the views [`"SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."GRANTS_TO_USERS"`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_users.html) and [`"SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."GRANTS_TO_ROLES"`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_roles.html) in combination have the information you need,
but are only accessible to `ACCOUNTADMIN`

You also have:

```
SELECT * FROM "MY_DATABASE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."ENABLED_ROLES";
SELECT * FROM "MY_DATABASE"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."APPLICABLE_ROLES";
```

The latter looks like a good place to start.

**Edit primo 2023:**

If you want to make your own near-instant expanded `GRANTS_TO_ROLES`, you can follow these lines:

- Get roles with `SHOW ROLES; RESULT_SCAN()`
- Iterate over roles above with `SHOW GRANTS TO ROLE <role>; RESULT_SCAN()`
- Iterate over `ALL_USER_NAMES()` with `SHOW GRANTS TO USER <user>; RESULT_SCAN()`
- Finally create a `SELECT` statement with a recursive Common Table Expression expanding the nested roles

Comment: It's worth noting here that `grants_to_users` data will be latent (up to 2 hours according to [current docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_users.html)). `information_schema` will likely be available faster than that.

Comment: The latency might have improved lately, as of primo 2023 I'm experiencing ~30 min delay in eg. GRANTS_TO_ROLES.  GRANTS_TO_USERS seems to be faster < 10 mins.

Answer (score -1):

i found the best way to find all roles with inherited roles.

just run below SQL.

```
SELECT CURRENT_AVAILABLE_ROLES()
```

Comment: Please, no promotion in answers. See our help center for further info, answers should [not contain signatures or taglines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), and our community [tends to flag self-promotion as spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: This works for the current user, but not an arbitrary user.